# Download apk with x86 native binaries

Tags: google-play-store, apk, android-emulator, android-x86, x86-processors

Is there a way to download APKs with x86 native binaries (from google play)?

With [raccoon](http://raccoon.onyxbits.de/), I can download APKs directly, but it only add an Note 5 as a device. That causes, that the APKs I download only contains ARM binaries.

I need the APK to run Apps in the AVD (which is much much faster if I use a x86 android)

Comment: That's because of the preconfigured device settings. Take a look at Raccoon's partner-product *DummyDroid* and generate yourself an appropriate device profile. You can find *DummyDroid* on the author's website.